# Can I license a program under Apache License 2.0, if it is using/including Eclipse Link (EPL or EDL)?

Tags: licensing, apache-license

Can I license a program under Apache License 2.0, if it is using/including EclipseLink?
(EclipseLink under Eclipse Public License or Eclipse Distribution License)

I did not change anything in EclipseLink.
I would realy like to distribute a Version that includes the needed EclipseLink jars, so that it is working "out of the box".

Answer (score 1):

For most things you might want to do, yes.

There are differences in the terms so that some situations could result in problems. As always, before you do anything like commercial use or annoying someone big and nasty get competent legal advice. The advice will probably be: don't do it.

Make sure you read the licences and do what they say you have to. EPL seems to require their copyright notice on your distribution, so do that. Full disclosure of what components you used and including copies of everyone's licence in your distribution should keep everyone happy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem at some point and what I do is to distribute the build configuration i.e. the Maven pom.xml. This way you distribute the source to something that will pull Eclipselink but not package or hardwire it within. Then the users are then bound to both licenses. In my case the users are also free to stay at Hibernate or simply JPA.